# Is there a way to group often used tables and queries in SSMS?

Tags: ssms

I am not a DBA by training, but due to role shifts I am having to modify and maintain tables and stored procedures fairly often. I would like to visually group tables and stored procedures together in a sort of shortcuts folder. So that when I need to open several related views I don't have to scroll all over the database. Is something like this possible?

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I am just trying to make this part of my job a little less tedious.

Comment: Not really. You can filter the schemas being shown in SSMS to reduce visual clutter, though. You could also make synonyms for these objects and put them in a dedicated schema to filter off of, but I'd recommend against doing that *just* out of ease of navigating in SSMS.

Comment: @LowlyDBA That's unfortunate. However, I understand this is a niche complaint. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

I have my db objects in source control with one file per table, view, SP etc. When working on a project I create a working folder and paste into it a shortcut to the relevant objects. Note this is a shortcut, not a copy, so the real files remain in the place source control expects to see them. I can drag into SSMS from the shortcut.